# How do implement RealM with a MySQL

Tags: mysql, react-native, realm

I'm currently building a react native application that involves sharing data between multiple clients.  I already have a Web-app with a MySQL database near completion.  I need to know how to use RealM with react native in order to provide offline local storage while including functionality to update the MySQL database when online.

Does anyone have any useful tips or resources on how to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: You need to expose a REST client from your "web-app with MySQL database".

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have two options, and you aren't going to like either one of them:

1. Throw away the application you've written and start over.
2. Don't use Realm.

Realm isn't a component which can integrate with an existing application an its database. Instead, it's a *replacement* for a traditional SQL database -- the expectation is that you use Realm as the primary storage for all your data. Its synchronization features depend on it having full control over how objects are stored in the database.

Comment: It's MySQL though, so any kind of synchronization would happen manually through a REST API on a backend anyways.

Comment: But you don't *have* to "not use Realm". you can still use Realm as local database in your app

Comment: Thanks of the clearing that up for me @EpicPandaForce.  Option 1 would definitely be the more costly of the two options, and I am not married to using Realm. It just seemed to be the best option from the research that I had done, but I wasn't sure never having used it myself.  Could you point me to any documentation of a REST API or an recommendations on what local database you would use in combination with the appropriate rest API